# NodeJS UDP one server multiple client and ports and help on understanding port behaviour

Tags: node.js, udp, port, wifi, one-to-many

thanks in advance for you help if you are reading this.

I have a code that i wrote and it's working. At least it does what i need perfectly. But i think it might be doing some side effect to my WIFI network. A script in NODEJS sends udp packets regularly to different devices that are connected thru wifi. The devices are never responding to that packet but on purpose, i just want the "server" script to send updated info to the devices and "forget" about what it sent. I have a packet send scheduled , say per example, every 100milliseconds. But i need to keep stuff as light as possible. My content is 29 Byte long. My device number can vary.
The code goes something like this kinda pseudo code:

```
const client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
for (z=1 , z== numberOfDevices, z++){
   if (sendFlag === 1) {
       client.send(NONE, 21324, myArgs[z], (err) => {});
   }
}
```

even skipped the error catching because it doesn't matter to me. i want it to work "blindly".
and i only create "client" once and never call "client.close();" because if i do that every packet will generate a new output port and i am guessing that it can't be good for the router nor the machine running the node script.

if i dont call client.close(), like now, the output port remains always the same.
But it also will remain the same even if the target IP address changes. like:
port 50100 to IP1
port 50100 to IP2
port 50100 to IP3
and so on...
And i don't know if that can have any impact on the router if i am running the script for a big while, like 10 hours the wifi connection gets really slow. Even after i stop the server. And if the router is rebooted and i run the script everything is wonderfull and fast.

I would like to make possible that something like this happened:
port 50101 to IP1
port 50101 to IP2
port 50103 to IP3
and so on... for all the time that the script ran.
this seems like something that server.bind would help me , like binding a port for each ip but i am not that good at coding and i simply cannot make it work like that anyhow. If someone could help me i would not be able to thank you enough! Nodejs scripts examples are pretty based on client-> server comunication between two devices and this case i need one to many and i can't find some decent resource that i can learn from.

Side question is if can the same source port sending to multiple clients can have impact on networks.
Thanks!

Comment: Why? There is no advantage. Just pointless extra programming. Just do what you're doing, use the same socket for the life of the server process.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. The reason why is exactly what i am trying to figure out. Im trying to compare if the network problems that i am experiencing can have anything to do with having the same port producing packets for different destinations.

Comment: If you are having a problem you should post the problem, not your guess at a possible solution. But have you considered multicast? It would cut the traffic to *1/N* of what you have now, where *N* is the number of clients.

Comment: Maybe you are right but still i would like to know how to master that port control and take on that for trying to analise the rest

Comment: Multicast i did but info on each packet is not the same for each device.

Comment: Using new ports won't solve your problem so it is pointless telling you how to do it, not that it's neceesary because you already know. Unclear what you're actually asking here.

Comment: I’m asking how can i use a different single port for each ip destination for the life of the server process, regardless of if that solves any problem or not. And yes, i read that you consider that its ok as it is and that it would be pointless extra coding.